# Data center migration with Azure Migrate

Tags: azure, database-migration, express-router, azure-hybrid-connections, azure-migrate

Do you need hybrid connectivity with expressroute or S2S to execute a data center migration with Azure Migrate if your goal is to exit the data center?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know and as per this [**Microsoft Document**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-data-center-migration-just-got-easier/?msclkid=d76282d0cf6a11ec9f1441fc41efbf2b), we don't require any **EXPRESSROUTE** and **S2S** to execute a data center migration.

Comment: correct it is not required but ExpressRoute can speed things up considerably if you are migrating a large number of VMs.

Comment: Hey [Joy1979](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863884/joy1979), has it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot.